# including JavaScript SDK for facebook comment box

Tags: javascript, facebook, web-services, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

What do I need to do include JavaScript SDK ,so that I am able to use the facebook code for comment box :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1xxxxx34xx26x0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

I looked at [**this**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) page but I really haven't understood how to do this. I have hosted my website on google appengine which doesn't support php .I want to implement a comment box for my website.

Answer (score 1):

You put the first block of html on the line following the `<body>` tag in your page's html.  Then, you put the second block of html where you want the comments plugin to appear on your page.

Edit: Removed broken link.